# how Can I share a csv files from databricks without any download into a windows folder?

Tags: windows, csv, databricks

I'm using databricks notebook to generate a csv,
this csv is shared on file store. I want to share this csv with an end-user that does not have databricks.
If possible, place directly this csv on a shared folder like on Windows.

how can I ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use external file stores in Databricks Such as Azure Datalake or Amazon S3. You will need to connect that filestore and then write to that location. This all depends on the file store you choose but the docs are really good.

- [For Amazon S3 Get started here](https://docs.databricks.com/storage/amazon-s3.html)
- [For Azure Blob/Datalake Start here](https://docs.databricks.com/storage/azure-storage.html)

As an Aside if you choose Azure Datalake/Blob it can be mounted [like a drive onto Windows](https://medium.com/data-science-at-microsoft/how-to-mount-azure-blob-storage-to-your-local-windows-or-virtual-linux-machines-even-with-disabled-3008aeec3da8)